# Direct Sum and Intersection Query

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have been puzzling over a statement in Module Theory:
Let $N\leq P\leq M$ (i.e. $N$ is a submodule of $P$ which is in turn a submodule of an $R$-module $M$.)

Let $N'$ be another submodule of $M$.

Why is $P\cap (N\oplus N')=N\oplus (N'\cap P)$?

I am puzzled because elements in $P$ are of the form $p\in P$, while elements in $N\oplus N'$ are of the form $(n,n')$, which should have no intersection?

I tried to interpret it as such: We view $P$ as isomorphic to the module $\{(p,p): p\in P\}$. Then, their intersection will be the set $\{(x,y): x\in P\cap N=N, y\in P\cap N'\}$ which is equal to $N\oplus (N'\cap P)$.

Is the above interpretation correct?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Or more simply, $N\oplus N'$  denotes the *internal*  direct sum of $N$ and $N'$? Of course this supposes $N$ and $N'$ intersect trivially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure what the intended meaning was by whoever wrote that equation, but I wouldn't guess that your interpretation was what was meant.  I would guess that instead, the direct sums were meant as *internal* direct sums.  Then the equation $$P\cap (N\oplus N')=N\oplus (N'\cap P)$$ is a horribly sloppy way of writing the following assertion:

> Suppose that $N\cap N'=0$ (so that the submodule $N+N'\subseteq M$ is the internal direct sum of $N$ and $N'$).  Then $N\cap (N'\cap P)=0$ (so $N+(N'\cap P)$ is also the internal direct sum of $N$ and $N'\cap P$), and $P\cap(N+N')=N+(N'\cap P)$ (this is an equation between two submodules of $M$).

This assertion is easily proved: clearly $N\cap (N'\cap P)=0$ since $N\cap N'=0$, and if $x\in P\cap (N+N')$, we can write $x=n+n'$ for $n\in N$, $n'\in N'$, and then $n'=x-n\in P$ since $x,n\in P$.  Conversely, if $x\in N+(N'\cap P)$ then clearly $x\in N+N'$ and also $x\in P$ since $N,N'\cap P\subseteq P$.